# PHP CORS Proxy for Canvas Images

Tags: php, canvas, cors

I need a local CORS proxy to load images from an external source. These images should be rendered in the canvas object.
For this I use the solution from https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy

However no images are loaded but there is an empty response

This is the Part where Images should be rendered in a Canvas Object

```
loadImages() {
    this.images.forEach((value, index) => {
        const image = {};
        
        image.img = new Image();
        image.img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

        image.img.src = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + value.packshot;
        //image.img.src = '/proxy.php?csurl=' + value.packshot;

        image.img.onload = (() => {
            // some code
        });
    });
},
```

this works
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://download.falk-ross.eu/ws/picture/163_06_051_f-2015-nc_01.jpg

this doesn't work /proxy.php?csurl=http://download.falk-ross.eu/ws/picture/163_06_051_f-2015-nc_01.jpg

anyone knows advice?

Answer (score 2):

got it - with many thanks to this greate community. sometimes the solutions comes in when asking the question

```
<?php
$url = ($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : $_GET['url'];
$headers = ($_POST['headers']) ? $_POST['headers'] : $_GET['headers'];
$mimeType = ($_POST['mimeType']) ? $_POST['mimeType'] : $_GET['mimeType'];
$session = curl_init($url);

if ($_POST['url']) {
    $postvars = '';

    while ($element = current($_POST)) {
        $postvars .= key($_POST) . '=' . $element . '&';
        next($_POST);
    }

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
}

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers == 'true');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($session);

if ($mimeType != '') {
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType);
}

echo $response;

curl_close($session);
```